# Regex to find if string contains only special characters or mixture of digits and specials characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i need to write a regex in js to validate if the string contains only special characters and mixture of special characters and digits.

i mean it should not accept these

1. 123 (only digits)
2. 123@#@$12(mixture of both)
3. @#$@$(only specials)

and it can accept

1. 123fgfdg
2. @#$dfgdfg

Please consider other languages japanese and koreans

i have this code

```
function ValidateValue(str){
    if(trim(str).length == 0){
          getMessage(7); //if string is empty
     }if(/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str)){//check if the string contains special and digits 
          getMessage(21); //this part works fine for english but not for japanese or korean.
     }if(IsInteger(trim(str))){  
          getMessage(8);// if string contains only numbers
     }
}
```

Comment: Define "special characters". And should it accept `@#$123abc`?

Comment: Do you want to support only Chrome/Node.js that support ECMAScript 2018 Unicode categories in regex or any JS environment with ES5 support?

Comment: For the latest ECMAScript versions, use `if(/^\P{Alphabetic}+$/u.test(str))`

Comment: any js with ES5 support